# nginx issue with following all redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have two redirects in a file at /etc/nginx/redirect.conf:

```
rewrite /this-link https://www.google.com redirect;
rewrite /this-link-too https://mail.google.com redirect;
```

Attempting to go to http://www.example.com/this-link or http://www.example.com/this-link-too both go to https://www.google.com.

Is there a way to force exact matching?

Example config below:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name www.example.com;

index index.html;

error_page 404 http://www.example.com/error.html;

location / {
  try_files $uri @redirect;
}

location @redirect {
  include /etc/nginx/redirect.conf;
}
```

Comment: There is no such directive "redirect". What is your actual configuration?

Comment: Apologies.  I mistranscribed it.  It's @redirect.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even get that far into your post. I meant the "redirect" right at the top. That is a blatant syntax error.

Comment: Oh geez.  Mondays.  I fixed the syntax again.  They are rewrites.  This all does work on the server, it's just typing it here that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive accepts a regular expression, so `/this-link-too` matches `/this-link`, and thus your first rewrite always gets used. `Rewrite` should be avoided unless you actually need to match a regular expression or do substitutions.

You should consider using exact `location` matches with `return` instead.

For example:

```
location = /this-link {
    return 302 https://www.google.com/;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct.  I now have a locations.conf file that includes directly in server block, and everything is now working as intended!